# devirtualization in c++ with dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, templates

Here's the scenario. I have the job of increasing the efficiency of code that transfers huge amounts of data to local models from an ICD in a real-time simulation. This is the main function of this tool. However the Transfer class necessarily includes a pure virtual exec function that is inherited by other classes that implement the exec function to performs the transfer. I believe the code is nicely designed and works well, but just not fast enough, so that overflowing frames can happen. Since each transfer object is an implementation of the pure virtual function, the code will have a virtual pointer in each Transfer object. I've heard enough (e.g. from Alexandrescu) about how this can slow things down by having the vptr at the front of the cache. So I want to devirtualize this code (greatly simplified below) if possible:

```
Transfer.h

class Transfer
{

public:

    virtual void exec(void)=0;
}
```

one example of many different templates for different transfer types

```
ConversionTransfer.h

template<class fromType, class toType, bool negate_trans = false>

class ConversionTransfer : public Transfer
{
public:
    /// Move the data, converting the input type to the output type
    void exec(void);
};

//template class implementation
template <class fromType, class toType, bool negate_trans>:
void ConversionTransfer<fromType, toType, negate_trans>::exec(void)
{
    *(toType *)this->mToAddr = (toType)*(fromType *)this->mFromAddr;
}
```

The to and from types are not known at compile time, so the transfer objects are created dynamically during the initialization phase of the simulation.

Example of how this is used following the initialization phase:

```
Table.cpp 


Transfer * newTransfer = NULL;


//create the transfer object
newTransfer = new ConversionTransfer<int, int,
                        false>;

mTransfers.push_back(newTransfer);


void Table::exec(void)
{

    TransferList_t::iterator end(mTransfers.end());
    for (trans = mTransfers.begin(); trans != end; ++trans)
        (*trans)->exec();

}
```

mTransfers is a vector containing pointers to all the transfers objects. I was hoping you C++ experts could weigh in as to whether the devirtualization is possible and how best to accomplish it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't optimise based on hypotheses created from what you've heard. You need facts, so measure, measure, measure, and measure again.

Comment: Need to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help.

Comment: TrskalJM: Fair enough, but the code I entered is just the pertinent pieces from the transfer tool that works. I was hoping for some ideas that might help me restructure the classes to eliminate the need for a virtual table. Maybe that is not an appropriate question to pose to this forum. molbdnilo: I agree that I need to measure. The c++ transfer tool work well, but there is an older c version of this tool that is unacceptable for other reasons, but that is faster than the c++ code as regards the transfer functionality. I hoped there would be a way for the c++ code to run as fast or faster.